# Are "skill set" and "skill sets" both acceptable?

Tags: expressions, grammatical-number, attributive-nouns

Are the phrases *skill set* and *skill sets* both correct?

As I see it, *set* implies a single set of related skills whereas *sets* can be taken to mean multiple sets of skills around different concentrations.

Thoughts?

Comment: Exactly so. You can have several sets of related skills (skills in both cookery and karate, for example).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Skill* is a noun, not an adjective. However in that phrase it is used as a noun adjunct, so it serves as an adjective.

Aside from that, I agree entirely. "Well, that matches my skill set" and "The two jobs need completely different skill sets" being valid singular and plural uses, respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, and also the clarification between adjective and noun adjunct.

Answer (score 3):

In reference to all of one's skills, the term 'skill set' includes all of a person's skills with none left out of the fold or on the sidelines. 
But if we wanted to convey a breakdown of skills into different areas and components, the term 'multiple' can be used to more clearly convey a plurality of sets, as in 'multiple skill sets'. In this instance, 'sets' is plural.